# GitLab asking for passwort after adding SSH-Keys

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-18.04, ssh-keys

Dear StackOverflow community,

I created ssh-keys following this (https://gitlab.com/help/ssh/README) instruction. I added the ED25519 SSH key pair to the GitLab profile on the webpage and if I do `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` I do obtain the message `Welcome to GitLab, @username!`, so that far it seems to work.

However, I want to `git push` and `git pull` from my local repository to GitLab without typing my password every time. As far as I understand the SSH-keys, that should be exactly the thing they do, right?

EDIT:

my `.ssh/config` contains:

```
Host machine                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      User username                                                                                                                                                                                           
      HostName machine.webside.com
```

The `.gitconfig` contains:

```
[user]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        name = John Doe                                                                                                                                                                                   
        email = john.doe@email.com
```

and the `.git/config` contains:

```
[core]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        repositoryformatversion = 0                                                                                                                                                                         
        filemode = true                                                                                                                                                                                     
        bare = false                                                                                                                                                                                        
        logallrefupdates = true                                                                                                                                                                             
[remote "origin"]                                                                                                                                                                                           
        url = https://gitlab.com/johndoe/projectname.git                                                                                                                                              
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                                                                                                                                                         
[branch "master"]                                                                                                                                                                                           
        remote = origin                                                                                                                                                                                     
        merge = refs/heads/master                                                                                                                                                                           
[branch "branch1"]                                                                                                                                                                                  
        remote = origin                                                                                                                                                                                     
        merge = refs/heads/branch1                                                                                                                                                                  
[branch "branch2"]                                                                                                                                                                                        
        remote = origin                                                                                                                                                                                     
        merge = refs/heads/branch2
```

Comment: Show your `~/.ssh/config`, `~/.gitconfig`, and your repository's `.git/config`

Answer (score 5):

Your `.git/config` shows that your repository is accessed over HTTPS, therefore using username and password authentication.

If you want to switch to ssh, you also have to change your local GIT configuration, in addition to adding an SSH key.

GitHub has a very detailed tutorial about changing your GIT remote URL from a HTTPS to a SSH one: https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh
The steps described there are also applicable for GitLab, except that your remote URL will be something like `git@gitlab.com:<repo-url.git>` instead of `git@github.com:<repo-url>.git`

More or less, you just have to use `git remote set-url origin`.